# External Mic Switching Mid Call on Google Hangouts

Tags: google-meet

The Mac is closed over and a separate monitor is being used for the display. A webcam (Logitech C505) is being used for video and sound. Webcam mic is set as the default mic.

When Google meet call starts, default mic works perfectly. Mid call the mic reverts to the inbuilt Mac mic but this does not work as the mac is closed over. Webcam video is not affected.

I have no idea why this switch happens. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after the switch happens, can you manually go into the settings mid-call and switch it back to the intended mic?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Our company has Blue Yeti microphones and randomly (on everyone's MacBook Pro M1, the speaker setting will switch to the USB microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. This fix recommended here worked for me.
https://support.google.com/meet/thread/171274934/microphone-source-changes-during-meet?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1193185)